# JQuery enable button based on select

Tags: jquery, select, button

I have a page that contains a collection of select's that are used to identify the columns in a text file. Each time a user identifies a column the selected option is removed from the other selects on the page. When the user has identified all columns the "submit" input needs to be activated so the user can move to the next step. I need a cleaver way to determine when all of the columns have been selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.repfolio.com/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.repfolio.com/Scripts/jquery.selectboxes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('.ct').bind('change', function() { updateControls(this); });
        }
    );
    function updateControls(c) {
        $('.ct').unbind();
        if ($(c).val() == 'Reset') {
            var opt = $(c).find("option[value!='Reset']");
            // if there are selects with value = '' then add this option back to them -- need to address this select too
            if ($(".ct").filter("[value='']").size() > 0) {
                $(".ct").filter("[value='']").each(function() {
                    $(this).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", $(opt).val()).text($(opt).text()));
                });
                var options = $(".ct").filter("[value='']:first").children().clone();
                $(c).find('option').remove();
                $(c).append($(options));
            } else {
                $(c).find('option').remove();
                $(c).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "").text("-- Select Column -"));
                $(c).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", $(opt).val()).text($(opt).text()));
            };
        } else {
            var s = $(c).children().filter('option[selected=true]');
            $(c).find('option').remove();
            $(".ct option[value='" + $(s).val() + "']").each(function() { $(this).remove(); });
            $(c).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", $($(s)).val()).text($(s).text()));
            $(c).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "Reset").text("Reset"));
        }
        $(".ct").filter("[value='']").sortOptions()
        $('.ct').bind('change', function() { updateControls(this); });
        if ($('select.ct option:nth-child(3)').length)
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'enabled');
    };
</script>
```

This is the section that enables the button:

```
if ($('select.ct option:nth-child(3)').length)
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'enabled');
```

Comment: Note: the file being mapped might contain 10 or more columns but only 5 may need to be identified.

Comment: Can you give a specific example for list of columns in file, selects content walkthourgh about what should happen when user selected value in the select control ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled', 'enabled');
```

disabled attribute can be set only with 'disabled'. And if you want to enable a button you just set an empty string like this :

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled', '');
```

But in this case I recommend you use ".prop" :

```
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
```

You can read more about the difference between ".prop" and ".attr" in the jQuery.api